# Rename Pages/Shared directory in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5 Razor Pages. The common templates go in `Pages/Shared`, but I need to rename it to `Pages/Foo`.

How do I instruct the runtime to look for files in `Pages/Foo`?

I think it's possible in `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

```cs
services.AddRazorPages(options => {
  options.Conventions.???      // what goes here?
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paths used to locate Razor Pages views are defined in [`PageViewLocationFormats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorviewengineoptions.pageviewlocationformats), which is a property of `RazorViewEngineOptions`. You can manipulate this collection to customise these paths.

Here's an example:

```
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorOptions(o =>
    {
        var indexOfPagesShared = o.PageViewLocationFormats.IndexOf("/Pages/Shared/{0}.cshtml");

        o.PageViewLocationFormats.RemoveAt(indexOfPagesShared);
        o.PageViewLocationFormats.Insert(indexOfPagesShared, "/Pages/Foo/{0}.cshtml");
    });
```

There's a tonne of different approaches to modifying the list, but this example shows how to replace the existing `/Pages/Shared` path with `/Pages/Foo`. It makes assumptions about the root (`/Pages`) and the file-extension, but these are typical.

Note that if you're using areas, there's also an [`AreaPageViewLocationFormats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorviewengineoptions.areapageviewlocationformats) property.

Comment: Looks [like this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.RazorPages/src/DependencyInjection/RazorPagesRazorViewEngineOptionsSetup.cs#L35) in the source. Pity it's not documented officially, as that magic string could change at any time. But it works, thank you.