# How to change the name of a .cshtml file in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack, razor-pages, asp.net-core-5.0

My environment: ASP.NET Core 5 with RazorPages, Webpack 5.

In razor pages (`.cshtml`) that reference svg files, I want to inline them. This is something Webpack can do (via a plugin), but I'm not sure how to integrate these two tech stacks.

I could write templatised cshtml files, and populate them via webpack:

```
ContactUs.cshtml.cs
ContactUs.cshtml                     <------ read by webpack
ContactUs.generated.cshtml           <------ generated by webpack
```

But then how do I force msbuild / aspnet to use the generated file (`ContactUs.generated.cshtml`) instead of the template file (`ContactUs.cshtml`) when building?

I suspect the answer is to use `IPageRouteModelConvention` but I'm unsure how.

(A dirty workaround is to instead use the filenames `ContactUs.template.cshtml` and `ContactUs.cshtml` but I prefer something like the above, as "generated" is clearer.)

To simplify the problem:

The compiler looks for `Foo.cshtml.cs` and `Foo.cshtml`.

How do I tell it to instead look for `Foo.cshtml.cs` and `Foo.generated.cshtml`?

Comment: The problem isn't the compiler or the names expected by Razor Pages. It's the names generated by whatever you used to generate the extra files. *That's* what needs to change. How did you generate those files? A file with a `cshtml` extension is the page itself, not just part of the page. What do the generated files contain? Could you convert them to partial pages and include them in the actual page?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Agreed - you're referring to the workaround I mentioned above, which works. But I prefer to change the convention somehow using `IPageRouteModelConvention` I just don't know how. Since the old T4 days, a file named "foo.generated.bar" was always understood to be generated and outside source control - so I want to replicate that paradigm here. I'm sure it's possible somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading the app, the framework loads for you a set of `PageRouteModel`s which is auto-generated from the razor page folders (by convention). Each such model contains a set of `SelectorModel` each one of which has an `AttributeRouteModel`. What you need to do is just modify that `AttributeRouteModel.Template` by removing the suffixed part from the auto-generated value.

You can create a custom `IPageRouteModelConvention` to target each `PageRouteModel`. However that way you cannot ensure the routes from being duplicated (because after modifying the `AttributeRouteModel.Template`, it may become duplicate with some other existing route). Unless you have to manage a shared set of route templates. Instead you can create a custom `IPageRouteModelProvider`. It provides all the `PageRouteModel`s in one place so that you can modify & add or remove any. This way it's so convenient that you can support 2 razor pages in which one page is more prioritized over the other (e.g: you have `Index.cshtml` and `Index.generated.cshtml` and you want it to pick `Index.generated.cshtml`. If that generated view is not existed, the default `Index.cshtml` will be used).

So here is the detailed code:

```
public class SuffixedNamePageRouteModelProvider : IPageRouteModelProvider
{
    public SuffixedNamePageRouteModelProvider(string pageNameSuffix, int order = 0)
    {
        _pageNameSuffixPattern = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageNameSuffix) ? "" : $"\\.{Regex.Escape(pageNameSuffix)}$";
        Order = order;
    }
    readonly string _pageNameSuffixPattern;
    public int Order { get; }

    public void OnProvidersExecuted(PageRouteModelProviderContext context)
    {

    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuting(PageRouteModelProviderContext context)
    {
        if(_pageNameSuffixPattern == "") return;
        var suffixedRoutes = context.RouteModels.Where(e => Regex.IsMatch(e.ViewEnginePath, _pageNameSuffixPattern)).ToList();
        var overriddenRoutes = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        foreach (var route in suffixedRoutes)
        {
            //NOTE: this is not required to help it pick the right page we want.
            //But it's necessary for other related code to work properly (e.g: link generation, ...)
            //we need to update the "page" route data as well
            route.RouteValues["page"] = Regex.Replace(route.RouteValues["page"], _pageNameSuffixPattern, "");

            var overriddenRoute = Regex.Replace(route.ViewEnginePath, _pageNameSuffixPattern, "");
            var isIndexRoute = overriddenRoute.EndsWith("/index", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            foreach (var selector in route.Selectors.Where(e => e.AttributeRouteModel?.Template != null))
            {
                var template = Regex.Replace(selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template, _pageNameSuffixPattern, "");
                if (template != selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template)
                {
                    selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = template;
                    overriddenRoutes.Add($"/{template.TrimStart('/')}");
                    selector.AttributeRouteModel.SuppressLinkGeneration = isIndexRoute;
                }                                                                              
            }
            //Add another selector for routing to the same page from another path.
            //Here we add the root path to select the index page
            if (isIndexRoute)
            {
                var defaultTemplate = Regex.Replace(overriddenRoute, "/index$", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                route.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel()
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel() { Template = defaultTemplate }
                });
            }
        }
        //remove the overridden routes to avoid exception of duplicate routes
        foreach (var route in context.RouteModels.Where(e => overriddenRoutes.Contains(e.ViewEnginePath)).ToList())
        {
            context.RouteModels.Remove(route);
        }
    }
}
```

Register the `IPageRouteModelProvider` in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IPageRouteModelProvider>(new SuffixedNamePageRouteModelProvider("generated"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I get an error though: `AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: /Foo/Index.generated /Index`. Did it work for you?

Comment: Also, maybe it's easier to do something similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66048975/9971404)?

Comment: I've tested it in simple cases and it works. For your specific case, could you post more code of your pages (the method entries are enough, no need for detailed code)? Looks like you have `Foo` & `Index` pages? Try narrowing it down as much as possible so that I can take a look at and reproduce it on my side. For your shared link about `PageViewLocationFormats`, I don't think it can be customized easily to achieve the same result as by this solution (note about the view overriding I mentioned), it's also hard for you to target some specific views that way.

Comment: I have `/Pages/Foo/Index.cshtml.cs` and `/Pages/Foo/Index.generated.cshtml`. Then that error appears? I think it clashes with `/Pages/Index.cshtml`

Comment: so looks like you've already applied the trick with `PageViewLocationFormats` before? Let me try that on my side and see if I can reproduce it, I will update the answer if found anything wrong.

Comment: Yes I tried that trick but for a different problem. I hope to use the same trick here (because it's simple) but like you say it's not perfect. In fact I couldn't get it to work. But I hope your way is the solution.

Comment: I also tried [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59825461/9971404) but it also isn't working. I think your solution is the key, I will carry on experimenting to make it work, thank you.

Comment: I could reproduce the error as you told me, I've fixed it and updated the answer. Please check it out and test it on your own. It was an error in adding the second selector for default route, e.g: `/Index` for `/` and `/Foo/Index` for `/Foo`.

Comment: I've added this line `var defaultTemplate = ...` for you to easily find out what's updated.

Comment: Awesome.... Your fix killed the bug!!! But how do you create links? `<a asp-area="" asp-page="/Foo/Index">Foo</a>` is the normal way, but with this provider that link does not render. Is that related to this somehow?

Comment: well I think that's related to another issue, please describe what you want in another question. I don't think the solution used here has something involved. If you want to separate the concerns, just try not using the code here and see if your link is generated as desired. Note that without the code here, your page can be accessed fine with `/Foo/Index` but the rendered view is from `/Foo/Index.cshtml`, not from `/Foo/Index.generated.cshtml`.

Comment: Agreed, when this code is not used, then the link is generated no problem. When the codei s used then the links start misbehaving

Comment: well, I've just reproduced it on my side, yes it does cause another issue. Let me try fixing it and will update the answer :) so many issues, but I think it's not hard to fix, just right in the code I posted.

Comment: thanks for your appreciation, but upvoting should be done if you really find that the answers are helpful, not the answerers. So please don't upvote like that, SO system is smart enough to detect massive upvoting and will auto-restore the voting. Even massive downvoting is not possible :).

Comment: I've just updated my answer, there are several places to update, hope you can spot that yourself. Basically we need to update the `RouteValues` as well, also the `Index.generated` as loaded originally will make `SuppressLinkGeneration` be `false`, so even with `RouteValues` updated correctly, the link generated will look like `/Foo/Index`. So we need to set `SuppressLinkGeneration` to `true` for index route, so the link will be generated correctly to `/Foo`